# Union All in query on view changes table seek to scan

Tags: t-sql

I have a View, which uses union between 2 select statements. the select statements is on table with million rows which joins with 4-5 small tables.

There is one Procedure which have some query on view with some where clause.

I thought using Union ALl in my view will be faster compared to Union (result is guaranteed to distinct), but if i use Union ALl instead of Union my Procedure takes significantly high time.
I checked the query plan and major difference I notice is

1. when i use Union  in my view plan contains all seek on table.
2. When i use Union all in my view it takes Scan on all tables (60% cost)
3. View select statement has condition as MainTable.Column <> 10, if I use  Union plan shows as MainTable.Column > 10 Or MainTable.Column < 10. Whereas Union all plan shows <> condition. Even if i make my condition as explicitly > Or < , still Union all plan shows as <>

how to know why changing union to union all plan generated Scan instead of seek.

Comment: cause 'Union' returns unique set of rows and whereas 'Union all' returns not unique one.

Comment: It sounds as if there are a number of ways to write this query.  I had someone write a view once on a table using union that I was able to rewrite using CASE statements to get an 8x speed up.  However, without more information about your actual query, it is difficult to suggest how to rewrite it.

Comment: the view is for a reporting and pretty big with selecting 30 columns from 10 tables. There are left joins to slightly difficult to convert Union to Case statements.